# How python Naming and Binding working here? How the below given code is producing the result.?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I got this code on python.org

```
class A:
    a = 42
    b = list(a + i for i in range(10))
```

Here defined a = 42 and in the loop a + i is done but when i see the result it returns in b is.

```
A.b  
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I tried to understand it but couldn't. Can someone please reply how this code is working.
Not defining a = 42 doesn't make any error. Then how i is being added to a when a is not defined

Comment: Unless you *also* have a global variable `a = 0` somewhere te code you posted will throw a `NameError` exception. See the duplicate as to why that is.

Comment: Not defining a = 42 doesn't make any error. Then how i is being added to a when a is not defined

Comment: That is what I am saying, you have a *global* `a` with value `0`.

Comment: O yes, got it. a was defined globally. but again the question is that i defined a = 42 but in the next line it is giving error that global a is not defined. but local a should be available there.

Comment: I closed your post as a duplicate half an hour ago. :-) Go read the post I linked you to.